Из PHP писать в файлы формата LibConfib
Всем привет. Для настроек устройства используется веб, PHP.
Для хранения конфигов устройства, используется формат LibConfig.  (https://hyperrealm.github.io/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html#Configuration-Files). Какой модуль для PHP вы порекомендуете, для работы с таким форматом файлов? Необходимо Создавать, читать, писать.
В данный момент уже и веб PHP готов и формат уже достаточно жестко используется, изменять на другой не вариант.

Мы бы порекомендовали использовать более стандартные и гибкие способы хранения конфигов. В виде json или yaml или, на крайняк, прямо в виде php array. А про libconfig забыть
